# Converting a scipy.sparse matrix into an equivalent MATLAB sparse matrix

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, sparse-matrix, data-conversion

I have a `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix` that I want to feed into a MATLAB method (that is not written by me) using the [MATLAB Engine API for Python](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html). The posts I've seen so far are either about how to convert a MATLAB sparse matrix into a python equivalent or they require modifying the matlab code which I'd rather circumvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally I believe MATLAB use the `csc` like format.  But construction is (at least when I used it years ago) with `coo` style inputs - data, rows, cols.

I'd suggest making a sparse matrix in MATLAB, and saving it (in the pre-HDF5 mode) to a .mat.  Then load that with `scipy.io.loadmat`.  Then use that result as guide when writing a `scipy.sparse` matrix back to a `.mat`.

`scipy.sparse` has a `save` function, but it uses the `np.savez` to write the respective attribute arrays.  If you had MATLAB code that could handle `.npy` files, you probably could load such a save (again using the `coo` format).

===

A test.

Create and save a sparse matrix:

```
In [263]: from scipy import io, sparse                                                                          
In [264]: M = sparse.random(10,10,.2,'coo')                                                                     
In [265]: io.savemat('sparse.mat', {'M':M})
```

test load on Python side:

```
In [268]: io.loadmat('sparse.mat')                                                                              
Out[268]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Wed Jul  3 11:41:23 2019',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'M': <10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>}
```

So savemat converted the `coo` format to `csc` before saving.

In an Octave session:

```
>> load sparse.mat
>> M
M =

Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 10, cols = 10, nnz = 20 [20%])

  (4, 1) ->  0.41855
  (6, 1) ->  0.33456
  (7, 1) ->  0.47791
  (4, 3) ->  0.27464
  (2, 4) ->  0.96700
  (3, 4) ->  0.60283
  (10, 4) ->  0.41400
  (1, 5) ->  0.57004
  (2, 5) ->  0.44211
  (1, 6) ->  0.63884
  (3, 7) ->  0.012127
  (8, 7) ->  0.77328
  (8, 8) ->  0.25287
  (10, 8) ->  0.46280
  (1, 9) ->  0.0022617
  (6, 9) ->  0.70874
  (1, 10) ->  0.79101
  (3, 10) ->  0.81999
  (6, 10) ->  0.12515
  (9, 10) ->  0.60660
```

So it looks like the `savemat/loadmat` code handles sparse matrices in a MATLAB compatible way.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not very familiar with MATLAB, therefore I don't think I fully understand and have some questions open. To recapitulate, what you mean is that I should declare an unspecified sparse matrix in MATLAB, write it with hdf5write to a .mat file? Could you please elaborate on "using that result as a guide"?

Comment: The `scipy.io.loadmat/savemat` use the older versions of MATLAB .mat files.  I think they can handle sparse matrices in both directions.  I'm less familiar with other transfer approaches.  If you don't know MATLAB very well, this could be a hopeless task.

Comment: Okay, I'll see how far I'll come. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: OK, I had a chance to test sending a `scipy.sparse` matrix via `savemat` to Octave.  It works.